# -1 seconds later in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, timestamps

On one of the meta chatrooms just now, I posted a link and then posted "..." a second later. For some reason, the second message inserted above the first, and a time difference message showed up informing me I'd posted the first -1 seconds after the second:

[image: Screenshot of the above]

Comment: They can't get the pluralization of "one seconds" right, so don't raise issues about the pluralization of "-1 seconds". Oh. Wait. You're talking about it being a negative number, aren't you? Hasn't this problem occurred before (or in the near future)?

Comment: @andrew if it was "1", not "-1", it would actually say "second", not "seconds". Just sayin... :)

Comment: It happened for me too, but didn't see the `-1 seconds later…` message.

Answer (score 11):

I know some physicists who would like to talk to you. Also, what can you tell me about next week's lottery drawing?

Comment: Only that you don't win

Comment: @Michael: Well, that certainly allows me to avoid the risk, at least!

Comment: Unless you *were* going to win, and me telling you you weren't caused you to not win by not buying a ticket.

Comment: @Michael: I'm from Australia. Would you like any iocane powder?